# Can't login to Ubuntu GUI with correct password

Tags: 16.04, server, password, gui

Despite entering the correct password, I am unable to login to GUI in Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried few steps from the following [those questions on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=can%27t+login+with+correct+password+ubuntu),
but they did not work at all.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest switching to a terminal (eg. ctrl+alt+f4) and trying to login there.  If you can login file (proving your password is correct), it could be you've run out of space, and a command `df -hi` will show disk-free. The GUI requires space for temporary files, and is the first thing I check. These two (wrong password, no space) are the two first checks I do....

Comment: i am able to login from terminal but not from gui. Also i checked df -hi , there is no issue with disk space.  Besides i even following the steps from the following url as well but even this did not help me out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Li-rTbyJLXc

Answer (score 4):

I see 2 possible problems.

### Wrong permissions on `.Xauthority` file.

Run `chown username:username .Xauthority` on a terminal in your home directory. Replace `username` with your actual username.

The `.Xauthority`-file can be found in each user home directory and is used to store credentials in cookies. You can find more info on X authentication and X authority in the [xauth man pages](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-xauth/) (type `man xauth` in a terminal). If you are not the owner of this file you can't login since you can't store your credentials there.

### Broken packages and dependencies.

Start Ubuntu in `recovery mode` from grub, select `dpkg` wait until it finishes and you are done.

Comment: While your solution might work, may I suggest you expand what you think triggers the error and how your command fixes it?

Comment: I added second cause and fix and more info, I hope you are happy :)

Comment: Your edit is a big improvement. I've been so bold to change your formatting and also did some rewording. Feel free to [access](https://askubuntu.com/posts/998634/revisions) the version history and revert it back to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! My English isn't very good.

Comment: I tried sudo chown bsaitechnosales:bsaitechnosales ~/.Xauthority

[prev]
chown: cannot access '/home/bsaitechnosales.Xauthority': No such file or directory
[/prev]

Please advise

Comment: AsenM, You mentioned Start Ubuntu in recovery mode from grub, select dpkg wait until it finishes and you are done.  Here my question is when you say select dpkg means what command do you want me to run. Was it 
dpkg --configure -a command or
apt-get update command or
apt-get install -f command or
apt-get dist-upgrade command or

Comment: You saved me! Big hug for you. Damn covid-19!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling onto the same issue:

It also might be the case that uppercase (or any letter requiring Shift) character is not correctly detected as you type due to system lag caused by default graphics drivers.

Just substitute the use of **Shift** key with **Caps-Lock** to input your multi-case password and see, it might just work as it did for me.

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

In my case, enabling the Wayland option in the settings symbol worked.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem can also arise due to filesystem errors.

- Login to tty mode from login screen( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> ).
- Use **`df -aTh`** command to see if the **`/home`** partition(say `/dev/sda9`) is mounted and verify the same from entries in **`/etc/fstab`**.
- If your home folder partition is not mounted, then you need to mount
  it using:

  ```
  sudo mount -a
  ```
- Finally, restart GUI using the command:

  ```
  sudo service lightdm restart
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
chown username:username .Xauthority 
chown username:username .ICEauthority
```

on a terminal in your home directory. Replace username with your actual username.